# Recreating Grails project in Intellij IDEA

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I have a directory with an Old (2013) Grails project I need to modify. The IDE used at the time was Intellij IDEA 14.

How can I recreate the project using Idea 2016? Is there a way to know:

- What Grails version it was compiled with
- What plugins are needed

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into `application.properties` on project root directory, to find out what Grails version the application is using, specifically `app.grails.version` property.

In terms of plugins, if you are referring to Intellij specific plugin, version 15 comes with Grails plugin, you just have to make sure you have installed Grails SDK.

But if you are referring to what plugin or other dependencies are required for the Grails application, everything is defined in `Configuration/BuildConfig.groovy` file.

Make sure you run the following command, before executing `run-app`:

```
clean

refresh-dependencies
```

Comment: What I meant was BuildConfig.groovy as oppose to Config.groovy. I've updated my answer.